# What does "draw back a stump" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does it mean to "draw back a stump" in this sentence?

> "Keep touching me like that, and you'll draw back a stump."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It literally means when you draw your hand back to you, you will have a stump. Your hand or digits will be cut off.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Huh? draw hand back where? hand cut off?  please elaborate more. thx

Comment: "Draw" is being used with the meaning "pull".  Your hand is near the other person, and the threat is that they will cut your hand off, so that when you pull your arm back towards yourself, there will be a stump, which would be the arm with no hand attached.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the definition from the [Urban Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/draw-back):

> **draw back a stump**
>
> A threat that you will cut off
>   someone's fingers, hand, arm etc.
>   unless they stop bugging or annoying
>   you (hopefully not literally). An
>   amputated limb is called a stump, so
>   unless they stop touching you, you'll
>   cut something off and they will draw
>   back a stump...not a hand.
>
> *You touch me again and you'll draw back a stump!*

It seems to be accurate. At least that was the meaning that the phrase had in three different usages that I found:

1) *Keep touching me like that, you'll draw back a stump.* 
[American Psycho](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/american-psycho?before=1294273805) (film)

[image]

2) Suspect : *Get your finger out of my face, bitch!*
Sara : *You touch me again, draw back a stump!*
[CSI](http://www.learnglish.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/eng/3710/Draw-back-a-stump) (television series)

3) [This picture:](http://cheezburger.com/TemplateView.aspx?ciid=2407532)

[image]